# Proper way to add a publishing target to the Sitecore Publishing Service

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

We're trying to migrate to the standalone [Sitecore Publishing Service](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service.aspx) (3.1 Update-1).

We have an environment that has two publishing targets (web and web2) and are trying to replicate this configuration in the new service.

However, while I see that we can add any connection string definitions we want, I don't see a way to add new publishing targets via the command line. Instead, it appears we need to update the \config\sitecore\publishing\sc.publishing.xml file to add a new `DefaultConnectionFactory` and `StoreFactory`.

Is manually updating the XML file the proper way to setup an additional publishing target with the Sitecore Publishing Service, or is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax to add connection string to Publishing Service via command prompt:

```
.\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host configuration setconnectionstring web2 ‘user id={user};password={password};data source={target_server};database={target_database};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;’
```

However there is no command prompt to add publishing targets.

You need to do it as you mentioned manually in publishing xml.

After all these steps are done, you need to apply the changes by running this command in command prompt:

```
Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host schema upgrade --force
```